# Customize no result page

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have a problem with no result page. I have a search box, if you find something then u can see "Search result : ", but if u didnt find then u can see "No Search result : ". I want to remove this NO before search result, but I dont find any solution for this. I tried already many different functions and css, but nothing .. I want to remove this NO, or whole this line (No search result : ).

This is what I have atm in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'tc_search_results_title' , 'my_search_results_title');
function my_search_results_title(){
  $my_search_results_title = __('Search result :', 'customizr-child');
  return $my_search_results_title;
}

add_filter('tc_breadcrumb_trail_items', 'search_results_breadcrumb');
function search_results_breadcrumb( $trail ){
  if ( ! is_search() )
    return $trail;

  $_last = sizeof($trail) - 1;
  $_search_string = __('Search result: ', 'customizr-child');
  /* or you an use the function used for that other snippet to have the same title, in this case remove the comment of the line below */
//  $_search_string = my_search_results_title();

  if ( is_paged() )
    $trail[$_last] = '<a href="' . get_search_link() . '" title="' . sprintf( esc_attr__( 'Search result &quot;%1$s&quot;' , 'customizr' ), esc_attr( get_search_query() ) ) . '">' . sprintf( '%2$s &quot;%1$s&quot;' , esc_attr( get_search_query() ), $_search_string ) . '</a>';
else
  $trail[$_last] = sprintf( '%2$s &quot;%1$s&quot;', esc_attr( get_search_query() ), $_search_string );

  return $trail;
}

add_filter( 'tc_no_result_content', 'my_no_result_content');
function my_no_result_content() {
    return '<div class="tc-content span12"><h1>Didnt find anything, try again</h1></div>';
}
```

I use Customizr child theme in Wordpress

Maybe somebody can help me with this.
Thanks !

Comment: So, did you find out where in the code is that string? `search.php` perhaps?

Comment: In customizr theme is no search.php file. But I really need to delete this NO front on Search result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong filter. You'll have to use `tc_search_results_header_content` instead and replace the `No` string. You can also use to original part of code and remove the unwanted part, something like:

```
function my_search_results_header_content ($content) {
    return sprintf( '<div class="row-fluid"><div class="%1$s"><h1 class="%2$s">%3$s%4$s %5$s </h1></div><div class="%6$s">%7$s</div></div>',
        apply_filters( 'tc_search_result_header_title_class', 'span8' ),
        apply_filters( 'tc_archive_icon', 'format-icon' ),
        '', // Original uses: have_posts() ? '' :  __( 'No' , 'customizr' ).'&nbsp;' ,
        apply_filters( 'tc_search_results_title' , __( 'Search Results for :' , 'customizr' ) ),
        '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>',
        apply_filters( 'tc_search_result_header_form_class', 'span4' ),
        have_posts() ? get_search_form(false) : ''
    );
}
add_filter('tc_search_results_header_content', 'my_search_results_header_content');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But, if u know how to disable search box what is on search result page, then I'm very happy :D I have already search box in header, and if search result is positive, then I got 2 search box..